# How to return a concrete implementation based on a variable(Enum/Object)

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-programming, generic-programming

I was wondering how can I return a concrete implementation given a variable as argument in a function.
This is my test code

```
public interface Items {
  String getName();
}


public class Car implements Items{
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "Car";
  }

  public void drive(){
    //To something
  }
}

public class Shelf implements Items{
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "Shelf";
  }
  public String getBooks(String bookName){
    return bookName;
  }
}

public enum Item {
  CAR(Service::getCar),
  TABLE(Service::getShelf),
  ;
  Function<Service, ? extends Items> serviceFunction;
  Item(Function<Service, ? extends Items> serviceFunction) {
    this.serviceFunction = serviceFunction;
  }
}

public class Service {
  public Car getCar(){
    return new Car();
  }
  public Shelf getShelf(){
    return new Shelf();
  }

  public Items getItem(Item item){
    return item.serviceFunction.apply(this);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Service service = new Service();
    service.getItem(Item.CAR).getName();
//    service.getItem(Item.CAR).drive(); // This is not valid.
  }
}
```

So what I want is based on that enum I should be able to execute a set of functions related to that enum without passing the implementation identifier itself.

I know I can do this. And I will work but I was thinking of getting the concrete implementation without passing `Class<T> klass`.

```
public <T extends Items> T getItem(Item item, Class<T> klass){
  return (T) item.serviceFunction.apply(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Service service = new Service();
  service.getItem(Item.CAR, Car.class).drive();
}
```

Comment: I think you're a bit overenginnering this, why not just return the object directly? (Or use dependency injection library instead of a service locator pattern (the latter is an anti-pattern), I personally like [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation))

Comment: What happens if I do `service.getItem(aDynamicEnumValue).drive()`? How will the compiler know whether that is valid if `aDynamicEnumValue`'s value is based on, say, user input?

Comment: @jeuxjeux20 Yeah I can understand it can be a bit over engineering. But I am want to use this piece of code for a library . I don't want to put Guice dependency in a small library. Most of the modules will not have guice or different version...  Dont want to go in that complexity...

Comment: @Sweeper totally agree with you... I am overthinking a flawed design...